# MySQL JOIN ignoring NULL values

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL with a JOIN, if I run this, it ignores records that have NULL values in the group_id in the users table. Therefore, I get less results

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.email, g.group_name 
FROM users u 
JOIN groups g USING (group_id) 
WHERE u.year=2017
```

However, If I run it without the JOIN like this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.email 
FROM users u 
WHERE u.year=2017
```

Then it gives all the users I need. Some of the users do not have the group_id set as this is not a required field. Is there a way to JOIN the NULL values too? Do I nee to have a NULL value in the groups table? This would not be possible as my group_id field in the groups table is NOT NULL and PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.email, g.group_name 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN groups g USING (group_id) 
WHERE u.year=2017
```

Answer (score 1):

Use left join if you want to get all users whether they have group_id or not

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.email, g.group_name 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN groups g USING (group_id) 
WHERE u.year=2017
```

or using your's version tweak on clause

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.email, g.group_name 
FROM users u 
JOIN groups g ON(u.group_id = g.group_id OR u.group_id IS NULL) 
WHERE u.year=2017
```